# Will changing the app name in itunes connect make the old name be available for another developer?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I accidentally used someones trademark as my app name.
I will upload a new binary and change the name in iTunes connect.
Will the old name now be available for other developers? Because I would like the help the trademark owner to register the name to his developer account for a totally new app.

How long would the timeframe be between me releasing the uploaded app with new name to the app store and the name being available for others? Maybe somewhere between "Developer released" and "ready for sale"?

Comment: Just did the procedure.... It is available immediately after "ready for sale".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I don't know if there is any published documentation on this, but you can verify it yourself by changing the name and then creating a new test app to see if it lets you select your previous name.